# How to fix this error in the following code?

Tags: java

I have a code. It has errors, I want to know how to fix the error. The error is corresponding to this line: public void start(Stage primaryStage)

The code is shown as follows:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DescriptionPane extends BorderPane{
    /** Label for displaying an image and a title */
    private Label lblImageTitle = new Label();

    /** Text area for displaying text */
    private TextArea taDescription = new TextArea();

    public DescriptionPane() {
        // Center the icon and text and place the text under the icon
        lblImageTitle.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);
        lblImageTitle.setPrefSize(200, 100);

        // Set the font in the label and the text field
        lblImageTitle.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", 16));
        taDescription.setFont(new Font("Serif", 14));

        taDescription.setWrapText(true);
        taDescription.setEditable(false);

        // Create a scroll pane to hold the text area
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(taDescription);

        // Place label and scroll pane in the border pane
        setLeft(lblImageTitle);
        setCenter(scrollPane);
        setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    }

    /** Set the title */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        lblImageTitle.setText(title);
    }

    /** Set the image view */
    public void setImageView(ImageView icon) {
        lblImageTitle.setGraphic(icon);
    }

    /** Set the text description */
    public void setDescription(String text ) {
        taDescription.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(taDescription, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("RadioButtonDemo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

I also paste the errors here. The errors are shown as follows. Can anyone give me a help to fix the problem. Thank you so much!

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class DescriptionPane is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.application.Application.launch(Unknown Source)
        at DescriptionPane.main(DescriptionPane.java:69)

Comment: `extends Application`

Comment: According to the error, this: `DescriptionPane extends BorderPane{`, needs to be this: `DescriptionPane extends java.fx.application.Application{`... that being said, I do not know if this will cause new problems :D

Comment: @npinti, no, it is not right

Comment: @achAmháin, no, it is not right

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be flawed. The implementation of the start-method and the calls of the setLeft-, setCenter- and setPadding-method exclude each other. The last three methods belong to the BorderPane-class and therfore require this class as base class. The BorderPane-class on the other hand has no start-method which could be overwritten.

Since this is a JavaFX application the class implementing the start-method must be derived from the Application-class as it is already stated in the comments.

Assuming this is a JavaFX-project, the easiest way to fix the problem is: Create a new public class, e.g. Main, which extends the Application class. Copy your start- and main-method inside this class. Inside the copied start-method replace also "Scene scene = new Scene(**taDescription**, 400, 200)" with "Scene scene = new Scene(**new DescriptionPane()**, 400, 200)". Remove the start- and main-method from your DescriptionPane-class.

[image]